# Как запустить Satis на удалённом сервере?

Tags: git, composer

Есть команда для запуска Satis:
`php bin/satis build satis.json response/`

Сам Satis лежит на сервер, например, `example.com/satis`

Как запустить команду на сервере удалённо?

Я попробовал сделать скрипт с командой `shell_exec('php bin/satis build satis.json response/')`, но столкнулся с ошибкой, когда Satis не может авторизоваться на Git:

```
Scanning packages
Failed to clone the git@gitlab.com:project/project.git repository, try running in interactive mode so that you can enter your credentials

In Git.php line 354:

  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@gitlab.com:project/project
  .git' '/var/www/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com-project.git/'                                                                         

  Cloning into bare repository '/var/www/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com-project.git'...                                                
  Host key verification failed.                                                
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights                          
  and the repository exists.                                                   


build [--repository-url [REPOSITORY-URL]] [--repository-strict] [--no-html-output] [--skip-errors] [--stats] [--] [ [ [...]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ключевая фраза в этой ошибке:

> Host key verification failed.

Небольшое гугление выдает такое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13364116/9435985):

```
ssh-keygen -R gitlab.com
ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Что произошло? В хранилище ключей был добавлен ключ от gitlab.com. Затем ключ изменился, и больше не подходит. А эти команды удаляют ключ, затем добавляют новый. Команды нужно выполнять из под пользователя, который клонирует репо.

Comment: ssh ключи ведь ещё надо указывать в настройках профиля на GitLab. Как быть, если он каждый раз будет меняться?

Comment: @Jack, вынести в конфиг и подставлять каждый раз при смене.